# LWC JS loadScript

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, locker-service, static-resources

I am trying to load this JS script: http://cdn.tagcommander.com/3468/tc_ENGIE_iframe.js
So I downloaded it as static resource and use loadScript in LWC:

```
import { loadScript } from "lightning/platformResourceLoader";

connectedCallback() {
    loadScript(this, "/resource/selfcaretagcommander").then(res => {
          console.log("file selfcaretagcommander loaded");
          console.log("window.tC: ", window.tC);
          console.log("window.tC.inArray: ", window.tC.inArray);
          console.log("window.tc_vars_adapter: ", window.tc_vars_adapter);
        })
          .catch(e => {
            console.log("error: ", e);
            console.log("file selfcaretagcommander failed to load");
            console.log("window.tC: ", window.tC);
            console.log("window.tC.inArray: ", window.tC.inArray);
            console.log("window.tc_vars_adapter: ", window.tc_vars_adapter);
          });
}
```

It goes to the catch block with error undefined but I see that the beginning of the script has been loaded as I can see the "tC" variable and it's content but it seems that at some point it stops loading as the functions at the end are undefined.

Comment: Your code doesn't import static resources from the `@salesforce/resourceUrl` scoped module. Check [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_resources) & [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.js_third_party_library) for sample code.

Comment: Hi Ludodo, in addition to what @arut said, note that 3rd party library is always difficult to use in LWC because of LockerService. You can refer to [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/locker-service-viewer) to check if the library use any unsupported API which will cause exception.